# How to delete tags in Tagify plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

I need to handle a dynamic button that will remove all the Tagify tags. The documentation for deleting all tags with jQuery is here: https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/#section-jquery

In the documentation it says:

```
// get the Tagify instance assigned for this jQuery input object so its methods could be accessed
var jqTagify = $input.data('tagify');

// bind the "click" event on the "remove all tags" button
$('.tags-jquery--removeAllBtn').on('click', jqTagify.removeAllTags.bind(jqTagify))
```

With this in mind, I have tried without success the following (can be seen here in **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gunqyew/)**):

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-test', function()
{
    var $input = $('#input-test').tagify();    
    $input.removeAllTags();
});
```

I also tried to create an approach closer to what the documentation states:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-test', function()
{
    var $input = $('#input-test');
    var _tagify = $input.data('tagify');

   _tagify.removeAllTags();
});
```

But in both situations the error is:

> Cannot read property 'removeAllTags' of undefined

I can't bind directly the remove function to a DOM element because buttons will be created on-the-fly.

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/zah2oLkr/

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc I can't use the variable `tagify` because the way I have my code, the plugin is loaded in a different file. I need to delete the values without accessing the variable `tagify`.

Answer (score 7):

> **It works for me this way**

```
 var prueba = '"Lic","ffff","asdasd","asdd","asd","dsdsd"';
 var $input = $('input[name=tags]');
 var jqTagify = $input.data('tagify');
 jqTagify.addTags(prueba);
 jqTagify.removeAllTags();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$input.data('tagify')` will not work and will return `undefined` because you did not initialize Tagify using jQuery per [the instructions in the docs](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#jquery-version):

```js
$('#input-test').tagify()
```

The above is how all jQuery plugins are used when applied to a DOM node - you first instantiate a jQuery object and then apply the jQuery plugin on it. Once you do it like that, the `data` property `tagify` will be available: `$input.data('tagify')`

Instead, you initialized it like the vanilla version, using `new Tagify(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

in jquery:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/3.16.3/tagify.min.css" />
<input name='tags-jquery' id="input-test" >
<button id="btn-test">
  Delete
</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tagify/3.16.3/jQuery.tagify.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $el = $('#input-test').tagify()
var jqTagify = $el.data('tagify')
var btn = $('#btn-test')
btn.on('click', jqTagify.removeAllTags.bind(jqTagify))
</script>
```